# Holding down a key pauses the timer

Tags: c#, .net

I have an astro game with 2 picture boxes. One with a fireball(asteroid), and another with a UFO. I am moving the UFO with left and right key, handeled in keydown event. The asteroid falls from top to bottom. I am changing Y coordinate in a timer tick event. My problem is that if I hold down a key, the asteroid stops from falling and starts again as soon as I release the key.

UFOpictureBox is 100,100 picture box

**Form Class**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int hearts = 3, score = 0;
    Point pozitieUFO, pozitieAsteroid;
    Asteroid asteroid = new Asteroid();
    Random random = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        KeyPreview = true;
        pozitieUFO = UFOpictureBox.Location;
    }
    
    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hearts = 3;
        score = 0;
        gameOverLabel.Visible = false;
        startBtn.Visible = false;
        exitBtn.Visible = false;          
        Controls.Add(asteroid);
        pozitieAsteroid = asteroid.Location;
        asteroidTimer.Start();
    }

    private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left) pozitieUFO.X -= 10; 
        if (pozitieUFO.X <= 12) pozitieUFO.X = 12;
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right) pozitieUFO.X += 10;
        if (pozitieUFO.X >= 792) pozitieUFO.X = 792;
        UFOpictureBox.Invalidate();
        UFOpictureBox.Location = pozitieUFO;
    }

    private void asteroidTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pozitieAsteroid.Y += score/5 + 5;
        if (pozitieAsteroid.Y > 420)
        {
            hearts--;
            heartsLabel.Text = "Hearts: " + hearts;
            if (hearts <= 0)
            {
                gameOver();
                return;
            }
            pozitieAsteroid.Y = 1;
            pozitieAsteroid.X = random.Next(12, 792);
        }
        if (asteroid.Bounds.IntersectsWith(UFOpictureBox.Bounds))
        {
            pozitieAsteroid.Y = 1;
            pozitieAsteroid.X = random.Next(12, 792);
            score++;
            scoreLabel.Text = "Score: " + score;
        }
        asteroid.Invalidate();
        asteroid.Location = pozitieAsteroid;
    }
    private void gameOver()
    {
        startBtn.Visible = true;
        exitBtn.Visible = true;
        gameOverLabel.Visible = true;
        asteroidTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

**Asteroid Class**

```
class Asteroid : PictureBox
{
    Random random = new Random();
    public Asteroid()
    {
        Width = Height = 50;
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        Image = Properties.Resources.fire;
        Left = random.Next(12,792);
        Top = 0;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you try another event than KeyDown?

Comment: Logically, you want the asteroid to update constantly, but that can get interrupted when other events take priority. it looks like you're making your game in Windows Forms, which can cause problems like that, as there's no standard update function. While it's probably not impossible, it'll be easier to understand if it was made in a more dedicated game engine, like XNA

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925033/a-delay-with-the-timer-when-a-key-is-held-down ?

Comment: @Fredy I tried with PreviewKeyDown but that event is not moving my UFO idk why. Also KeyDown event is moving my UFO only if I add this line in From constructor KeyPreview = true;

Comment: @DanielRad did you check the link (3rd comment)? I think there are your answers there.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I updated my question with all the code. u just add 1 picture box in form.

Comment: @Fredy I am checking third comment

Comment: no, sorry, key preview was a try.

Comment: @ThomasWeller http://prntscr.com/268kkjt

Comment: This is technically possible, the OS treats timer events as the lowest priority event for which a notification needs to be generated.  Keyboard input and painting gets a higher priority.  One other visible side-effect is that you'll see your program burning 100% core in Task Manager.  The fix in this code is simple, just delete the UFOpictureBox.Invalidate() statement.  It forces a repaint, but it does not actually have to be repainted since only the Location is changed.

Comment: How large is your UFO picture (in pixels)?

Comment: @Thomas it's 100/100

Comment: @HansPassant if I delete that row my UFO movement looks glitchy